# Careers loses my job responsibilities when editing profile in chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I was tweaking my CV and hit edit on one of my previous jobs. All my previous info filled out in the form but the responsibilities box was blank. I was uncertain what was going to happen so I backed up the job responsibilities into a word doc and hit submit. Low and behold yup in erased everything under that field. Now I'll have to restore the section from my backup. Sad panda :(.

My cv is at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dougturnbull if it helps.

I'm editing it in Chrome "13.0.782.220 m" (on Windows 7). Editing in IE9 works fine.

Comment: Is this still happening?  I can't get a repro out of Chrome...

Comment: Thanks for checking in @Jason. I'll try when I go home where I have chrome access.

Comment: @Punyon I should add I did try again and it was still happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening to me too.  I reproduced it 75% of the time on other job entries, but only once for each job/section.  The form does not actually lose any data, exactly.  It seems not to fetch it on the first attempt.  Once you hit 'cancel' and them come back then all of the data is present.  And once it does load the content then it does not occur again for that job/section.

- Chrome 15.0.874.106
- OSX 10.6.8

Comment: We're trying to repro over here...

Comment: @MattSherman Would it matter that I am in Europe?  Maybe there is some sort of race condition...it mildly smells that way.

Comment: Bah, I can't duplicate now :/